# How can I change the Display property of a Tab based on an Action in ClientScript?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

Im doing an customizaion and im trying to Display and Hode an Tab on the form based in some form Values and Action.

This is for a new Customization, im using Suitescript 2.0 and FieldChanged entry point.

```
define([], function(){
    function fieldChanged(context){
        switch(context.fieldId){
            case 'entity':
                var fornecedor = context.currentRecord.getValue({
                    fieldId: 'entity'
                });
                if (fornecedor != 38387){
                    context.updateDisplayType({
                        id: fornecedor,
                        isDisplyed: false
                    })
                }

        }
    }
```

I expect to get the current form to manipulate and can do those propertys, nad actually returns error to update the display type.

Comment: I believe the updateDisplayType is only available on the Field object and only takes the displayType option. Have you considered customizing your record form and loading the custom form when entity == 38387?

Comment: @NathanSutherland oh ok, do you know how can i do the change in Display property of a field by the standard/custom form? I didn't found an real example in the documentation, just samples creating a new custom form...

Comment: Are you trying to hide a field or a tab?

Comment: @NathanSutherland A tab, but now i think i can solve the problem hidding some fields...

Answer (score 0):

To hide a field, use:

```
var field = currentRecord.getField({
    id : 'textfield'
});
field.updateDisplayType({
    displayType: 'HIDDEN'
});
```

To hide a tab, create a custom form and dynamically load the desired form per customer.